# Second line graph not plotting as it should

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using shiny to plot two line graphs based on a field in the dataframe (municipality name), however the second one (Reported cases in black) is not plotting as it should when I change the municipality name, it is just a flat line, not sure what I am doing wrong

```
xx < -left_join(cases_pop_normalised, df_rna_inhab, by = c("Municipality_name" = "municipality_name"))

  ui < -fluidPage(titlePanel(h2("Blood Test Result System", align = "center")),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(

  selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
    label = "Choose a municipality:",
    choices = sort(x = names(table(unique(xx$Municipality_name)))),
    selected = "Westland")),


mainPanel(
  plotOutput("ts_plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("summary"))))

server < -shinyServer( function (input, output) {
datasetInput < -reactive({
  xx < -left_join(cases_pop_normalised, df_rna_inhab, by = c("Municipality_name" = "municipality_name")) % > %
  filter(Municipality_name == input$dataset) % > %
  distinct()
})
})

cases_pop_normalised$Date_of_publication < -as.Date(cases_pop_normalised$Date_of_publication)
df_rna_inhab$newDate < -as.Date(df_rna_inhab$newDate)
# plot time series
output$ts_plot < -renderPlot({
  wastewaterColor < -"red"
  dataset < -datasetInput()
  dataset$Date_of_publication < -as.Date(dataset$Date_of_publication)

  ggplot() +

  geom_line(data = dataset, aes(x = newDate, y = RNA_flow_per_100000), size = 1, color = wastewaterColor) +
  geom_line(data = dataset, aes(x = Date_of_publication, y = as.numeric(reported_norm)), size = 1, color = black) +   ###NOT PLOTTING PROPERLY 

  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Reported cases",

    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "Wastewater")
  ) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = MortalityColor, size = 10),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = wastewaterColor, size = 10)

  ) +
  labs(x = "Date") +
  ggtitle("test")

})
})

app < -shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here's a subset of the data

```
Date_of_publication Municipality_name   reported_norm   RNA_value   newDate     RNA_flow_per_100000
  10/24/2020             Westland           92.41223        2.16E+14    1/4/2021    1.08E+14
  10/24/2020             Westland           92.41223        2.54E+14    1/12/2021   8.09E+13
   10/15/2020            Aalten             84.80513        3.71E+12    9/9/2020    1.67E+12
   10/25/2020            Westland           84.25821        0           9/7/2020    0
   10/22/2020            Westland           78.8222         2.54E+14    1/12/2021   8.09E+13
   10/18/2020            Aalten             80.80513        5.71E+12    9/9/2020    1.67E+12
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with one of the following fixes: (1) change to a public dataset that is easily referenced; (2) generate random data for us, including `set.seed(..)` so that we have something representative and shared between you and us; (3) give us a representative sample of your data by posting the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is large enough to include sufficient variability, yet small enough to fit within the question.

Comment: And if you are really using the `shinydashboard` package, please be explicit about non-base R packages needed to reproduce this code (and no more); if not, then please remove the [tag:shinydashboard] tag.

Comment: Is the scale of `as.numeric(reported_norm)` anywhere in the range of `RNA_flow_per_100000` which seems to go as high as 2e14 on your plot? Maybe the flat line in this graph just reflects severely different data scales? You might have to define a transformation for the secondary axis, perhaps?

Comment: @r2evans I have included a subset of the data

Comment: Does this code actually work for you? `<-` and `< -` are different, and your code is generating errors for me. Further, your use of `as.Date` returns `character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`. All of this suggests that your sample data and sample code are not what you're using. While I appreciate providing reduced data, the code itself must still be syntactically correct to be able to do something. It can be problematic trying to parse through *"obvious shortcuts when asking the question"* and *"coding mistakes that are not showing the error **yet**"*.

Comment: @Oladapo, you are getting correct line at the bottom as a flat line in black color as the values (of `reported_norm`) are around 90 for most dates.  The other y-values in red (`RNA_flow_per_100000`) are in the range of 10^12 to 10^14.  Obviously, you need to fix the units and make both the variables to be in same units.